# Cannot Get Request Body Values without Content-type Header

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-functions, middleware, body-parser

I am using firebase functions to obtain values from request body and then perform actions accordingly, but I am getting 'undefined' when I try to get values. But when I use '**Content-type**' in header, My function is able to read request body values.
I also tried using middleware body-parser but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my functions code -

```
    const functions = require("firebase-functions");
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const app = express();
    function defaultContentTypeMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    req.headers['content-type'] = req.headers['content-type'] || 'application/json';
    next();
    }
    app.use(defaultContentTypeMiddleware);
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
     app.post('/', (request, response) => {
    request.headers
    const statusCode = parseInt(request.body.request_status_code);
    const txnID = request.body.merchant_transaction_id;
    const amountPaid = request.body.amount_paid;
    const userID = request.body.account_number;
    console.log(request.body);
)};
```

Please note that this Endpoint is called by third-party without headers and I am unable t parse request body values without content-type header.

Edit: Body parser is working when I use express locally on my machine but doesn't seem to work when I am using with Firebase function.

Comment: You could try replacing `bodyParser.json()` with `bodyParser.json({ type: '*/*'})`

Comment: @adsy still doesn't works :(

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message that you're getting?